# 403 Forbidden response from Alexa while using Alexa location API

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am getting 403 Forbidden when I try to get location details through Amazon location API.

I have enabled "Request users to access resources and capabilities." but still I get a 403 Forbidden response?

Comment: Please add your code into your original post, it won't fit in comments.

Comment: Please [edit] your code into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apiAccessToken` is included in all request to your skill, but it doesn't mean that you have access to resources. You will have to either explicitly grant access to your skill under `Settings` menu of your alexa skill or you will have to send a permission card to the user for consent.

In node sdk you can send a permission card like this:

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .withAskForPermissionsConsentCard(['read::alexa:device:all:address'])
      .getResponse();
```

where `read::alexa:device:all:address` is the permission value for `Device Full Address`.

Once the permission is granted, fire a GET request with `deviceId` and `apiAccessToken` to the specified `apiEndpoint`

Endpoint for Full Address is: `/v1/devices/*deviceId*/settings/address`

Country/region & postal code: `/v1/devices/*deviceId*/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode`

More info [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting 403 although I have granted the Permissions in the alexa developers console. Does it work only in the skill is published? How am I supposed to test it? Is there any way to verify in the jwt token if the permission is included or not?

Comment: When you enable it in developers portal and the user of the skill has to grant location permission explicitlt from the Alexa app. You can test it using the apiAcessToken and apiEndpoint.

Comment: Also experiencing this 403 error after granting permission.  There are multiple posts here and on the Alexa dev portal, so this may be an Amazon bug.

Comment: I too am getting a 403. The strange thing is Google provides a valid accessToken to my skill and when I use that token in the skill I get a 403. But when I use that exact same token and do a simple Https GET from my local dev box, it works fine.

Comment: @Patrick can you check whether the permission you gave and the permission-value you used are the same.

Comment: @MeyerDenney `apiAccessToken` is the token that you get from Alexa for fetching other information from Alexa itself. `accessToken` on the other hand is to identify the user in a resource server